# How do I make a QTreeView fill the whole dialog and resize with it?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTreeView and I can't find a way of making it fill the whole dialog window and resize with the window when it is resized.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QTreeView>

class MyDialog: public QDialog
{
public:
   MyDialog()
   {
       QHBoxLayout* l = new QHBoxLayout(this);
       setLayout(l);
       QTreeView* v = new QTreeView(this);
       l->addWidget(v);
   }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MyDialog d;
   d.exec();
   return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: @ChrisHBaker The solution should work, the sizePolicy of QTreeView is by default so that it occupies the whole window, so probably your problem is in another side, I recommend you provide a [mcve] and maybe an image to understand your problem